# Feeding vector into summarise_at

Tags: r, dplyr, paste

I'm sure it is something obvious since I'm an R novice, but I cannot figure out why the first approach is working while the second is not. Something is wrong with my use of "paste".

```
library(dplyr)

    data(mtcars)
    characteristics <- c('disp', 'hp')
    summarise_at(df, .vars = vars(characteristics), mean)
    characteristics <- paste('disp hp', collapse = ",")
    summarise_at(df, .vars = vars(characteristics), mean)
```

Comment: Did you try running `paste('disp hp', collapse = ",")`? It doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: I did. My question would be better framed as wanting to create a character vector from 'disp hp', although I may be wrong about this as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to summarise over `disp` and `hp` of `mtcars` why not use a simpler and more straigthforward approach, like so?

```
mtcars %>%
  summarise(across(c('disp', 'hp'), mean))
      disp       hp
1 230.7219 146.6875
```

Of yourse, you can also 'feed' your vector into the `across` operation:

```
characteristics <- c('disp', 'hp')
mtcars %>%
  summarise(across(characteristics, mean))
          disp       hp
    1 230.7219 146.6875
```

Using `summarise(across...)`would also take into account that so-called scoped `dplyr` verbs have now essentially been superseded by `across()`

Answer (score 0):

With help from a friend, I found the answer.

```
library('dplyr')

    data(mtcars)
    
    characteristics <- unlist(str_split('disp hp', ' '))
# the line above replaced characteristics <- paste('disp hp', collapse = ",")
    summarise_at(mtcars, .vars = vars(characteristics), mean)
```